# How does paging work in the list_blobs function in Google Cloud Storage Python Client Library

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I want to get a list of all the blobs in a Google Cloud Storage bucket using the [Client Library for Python](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python).

According to the [documentation](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/storage-buckets.html) I should use the `list_blobs()` function. The function appears to use two arguments `max_results` and `page_token` to achieve paging. I am not sure how use them.

In particular, **where do I get the `page_token` from?**

I would have expected that `list_blobs()` would provide a `page_token` for use in subsequent calls, but I cannot find any documentation on it.

In addition, `max_results` is optional. What happens if I don't provide it? Is there a default limit? If so, what is it?

Comment: I find this confusing too, looking for how to get all blobs in a directory, without paging?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`list_blobs()` does use paging, but you do not use `page_token` to achieve it.

## How It Works:

The way `list_blobs()` work is that it returns an iterator that iterates through **all the results** doing **paging behind the scenes**. So simply doing this will get you through all the results, fetching pages as needed:

```
for blob in bucket.list_blobs()
    print blob.name
```

## The Documentation is Wrong/Misleading:

As of 04/26/2017 this is what the docs says:

> `page_token` (str) – (Optional) Opaque marker for the next “page” of
>   blobs. If not passed, will return the first page of blobs.

This implies that the result will be a single page of results with `page_token` determining which page. This is not correct. The result iterator iterates through multiple pages. What `page_token` actually represents is which page the iterator should **START** at. It no `page_token` is provided it will start at the first page.

## Helpful To Know:

`max_results` limits the total number of results returned by the iterator.

The iterator does expose pages if you need it:

```
for page in bucket.list_blobs().pages:
    for blob in page:
        print blob.name
```

Comment: how could get a random subset of the files ? (e.g. there are millions of files, but i only want a random set of like, 1000)

Answer (score 2):

Please read the inline comments:

```
from google.cloud import storage

storage = storage.Client()

bucket_name = ''  # Fill here your bucket name

# This will limit number of results - replace this with None in order to get all the blobs in the bucket
max_results = 23_344 

# Please specify the "nextPageToken" in order to trigger an implicit pagination 
# (which is managed for you by the library).
# Moreover, you'll need to specify the "items" with all the fields you would like to fetch.
# Here are the supported fields: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects#resource

fields = 'items(name),nextPageToken'

counter = 0
for blob in storage.list_blobs(bucket_name, fields=fields, max_results=max_results):
    counter += 1
    print(counter, ')', blob.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm just going to leave this here.  I'm not sure if the libraries have changes in the last 2 years since this answer was posted, but if you're using prefix, then `for blob in bucket.list_blobs()` doesn't work right.  It seems like getting blobs and getting prefixes are fundamentally different.  And using pages with prefixes is confusing.

I found a post in a github issue ([here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/920#issuecomment-326125992)).  This works for me.

```
def list_gcs_directories(bucket, prefix):
    # from https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/920
    iterator = bucket.list_blobs(prefix=prefix, delimiter='/')
    prefixes = set()
    for page in iterator.pages:
        print page, page.prefixes
        prefixes.update(page.prefixes)
    return prefixes
```

A different comment on the same issue suggested this:

```
def get_prefixes(bucket):
    iterator = bucket.list_blobs(delimiter="/")
    response = iterator._get_next_page_response()
    return response['prefixes']
```

Which only gives you the prefixes if all of your results fit on a single page.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to extract only the subfolders out of a GCP bucket. Some of the other methods do work but only if they all fit in a particular page. I found something like the following that works for me:

```
blobs = self.gcp_client.list_blobs(bucket_name, prefix='subfolder/', delimiter='/')

for page in blobs.pages:
    print("Subfolders on Page: ", page.prefixes)
```

Sharing this answer if this helps anyone.

Answer (score 0):

It was a bit confusing, but I found the answer here

https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/iterators.html

You can iterate through the pages and call the items needed

```
iterator=self.bucket.list_blobs()        

self.get_files=[]        
for page in iterator.pages:
    print('    Page number: %d' % (iterator.page_number,))
    print('  Items in page: %d' % (page.num_items,))
    print('     First item: %r' % (next(page),))
    print('Items remaining: %d' % (page.remaining,))
    print('Next page token: %s' % (iterator.next_page_token,))        
    for f in page:
        self.get_files.append("gs://" + f.bucket.name + "/" + f.name)

print( "Found %d results" % (len( self.get_files)))
```

Comment: It's simpler than this. You don't need to do iterator.pages, unless you _want_ to see the pages. Simply doing `for blob in bucket.list_blobs()` will iterate through all the results. The paging will happen behind the scenes. I just posted my answer. I had not gotten around to it...